# moderncv and cvitem

Tags: moderncv

In moderncv I use `\cvitem` to point my skills. The problem is that if I use long text in a first column it gets breaked. Picture shows what I want to achieve.

[image]

first example is how it looks when I use `\cvitem{Something looooong}{Second entry}`. I can not achieve that second result with `\cvitem{Something looooong}{\\Second entry}` - if second entry is preceded by `\\` (new line), then it gets into first column where "Something looooong" text is. All in all - how to easily achieve this second example, please?

Comment: Not everybody knows `moderncv` in its details; would you please add a minimal document that illustrates the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add `\hfill` followed by `\newline` to put an empty line, so your entry will look like:

```
\cvitem{Something looooong}{\hfill \newline Second entry}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a "hack" that I was looking for! I didn't want to completely redefine `\cvitem`, instead I just wanted to change only one choosen line. Thank you again! Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can redefine `\cvitem` to use a `b{...}` column instead of the defualt `p{...}`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage{array}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}b{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}b{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
      \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\cvitem{Something looooong}{Second entry}

\end{document}
```

[image]